# load jcombo box item from data base when table name selected by another jcombo

Tags: java, mysql, jcombobox

```
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT BedID FROM '"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString()+"' WHERE = dischargedDate='-'");
```

I tried this code and it is worked when I change this code to like this;

```
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT BedID FROM 001_oncology WHERE = dischargedDate='-'");
```

I want to select table name via my first jcombobox. 001_oncology is one of my tables name on database and dischargedDate is a one column of the 001_oncology table and BedID is the primery key of the table

```
ResultSet rs = sexecuteQuery("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name LIKE '0%'");
```

I used above code to load table names into my first jacombobox

Anyone please help me soon and please check the image bellow of my interface image for better understanding.

[image: UI screenshot]

code for my first jcombo :

```
void loadCombo() {
 // jComboBox1.addItem(""); 
 try { 
  ResultSet rs = DB.getCon().createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name LIKE '0%'");
  while (rs.next()) 
  {  
    jComboBox1.addItem(rs.getString("table_Name")); 
    jTextField7.requestFocus();
  } }
  catch (Exception e) {  
   e.printStackTrace(); }  
    }
```

code for my second jcombo:

```
void loadCombo2() { 
jComboBox2.addItem("");
 try { 
 Connection c = DB.getCon(); 
 Statement s = c.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT BedID FROM '"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString()+"' WHERE = dischargedDate='-'");
  while (rs.next()) {
  jComboBox2.addItem(rs.getString("BedID"));
  } } 
  catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace(); } }
```

Comment: Can you post your full code?

Comment: code for myfirst jcombo


    void loadCombo() {
       // jComboBox1.addItem("");
        try {
            ResultSet rs = DB.getCon().createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name LIKE '0%'");
            while (rs.next()) {

                jComboBox1.addItem(rs.getString("table_Name"));

                jTextField7.requestFocus();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Comment: code for my second jcombo

    void loadCombo2() {
        jComboBox2.addItem("");
        try {
            Connection c = DB.getCon();
            Statement s = c.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT BedID FROM '"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString()+"' WHERE = dischargedDate='-'");
            while (rs.next()) {

                jComboBox2.addItem(rs.getString("BedID"));


            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Comment: Please edit your question and place the code there instead of using comments.

Comment: Use prepared statements instead of string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

What error are you getting? Is it giving you any errors?

Your ResultSet SQL statement would generate the following SQL statement which is wrong (In Oracle at least - not sure about other DBs)

```
SELECT BedID FROM '001_oncology' WHERE = dischargedDate='-'
```

You should not specify single quotes on the table name. Try this instead:

```
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT BedID FROM "+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString()+" WHERE dischargedDate='-'");
```

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= dischargedDate='-'' at line 1     -   I got this error for this also

and previously i got this error -  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''001_oncology' WHERE = dischargedDate='-'' at line 1

Comment: Remove the equal sign after the WHERE clause. i.e. 



ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT BedID FROM "+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString()+" WHERE dischargedDate='-'");

Comment: then i got this error   -   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''001_oncology' WHERE = dischargedDate='-'' at line 1

Comment: Did you remove the single quotes on the table name?

Comment: yes i try that also. but i want to select table name from my 1st jcombo

Comment: That error you have shown last shows that you have not changed the statement. It still has the = sign before the where clause and there is still a single quote around the table name. Change the statement to be as 



`ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT BedID FROM "+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString()+" WHERE dischargedDate='-'");

Comment: this is my code now - ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT BedID FROM '"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString()+"' WHERE dischargedDate='-'");   -   and error is  -  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''001_oncology' WHERE dischargedDate='-'' at line 1

Comment: Yes that is wrong. You have single quotes around the table name which is wrong. Please see the answer i provided and try and understand it.

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of my time, I'll rewrite one of your comboboxes to use prepared statements, the other one will be similar:

```
void loadCombo2() {
    try { 
        Connection conn = DB.getCon();
        PreparedStatement prepped = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT BedID FROM "+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString()+" WHERE dischargedDate=?");
        prepped.setString(1, "-");
        ResultSet rs = prepped.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {  
           jComboBox2.addItem(rs.getString("BedID"));
        } 
    } catch (SQLException e) {  
          e.printStackTrace(); 
    }  
}
```

This will prevent [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and is a better way to write this sort of code.

Comment: OK. But I really appreciate if you can explain about this prepareStatement and what are the advantages of it. thanx

Comment: Prepared statements are the preferred way to get variable information into JDBC. Google [sql injection](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+injection&oq=sql+inj&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57.1591j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8&qscrl=1) for more information than you'd ever want to know about it.